# Computable function $f = \Theta(g)$ with $g$ uncomputable

Tags: computability

This question most likely has a simple answer; however, I do not see it.

Let $g:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be an uncomputable function and $c$ a positive real number. Can there be a computable function $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that, for all $n$ large enough: $g(n) \leq f(n) \leq c \cdot g(n)$ (that is $f(n) = \Theta(g(n)$)?

Comment: I assume that (i) we are to find f that depends on g and c, and (ii) c must be greater than 1.

Comment: I interpreted the question as: for every g and c s.t. ... there is an f s.t. ...

Comment: But Noam's interpretation also makes sense: is there g, c, and f s.t. ... . and is more reasonable considering the title.

Comment: This can be a nice exercise in a "computability course": show that for some g there exist such f and for others not...

Comment: @Kaveh: I don't see it.  At least I see the closeness to the title, but "Let g:N→N be an uncomputable function" is well-established terminology unambiguously indicating that g is an unknown.

Comment: @Charles: I agree with you that "g" seems to be an arbitrary given function, that was how I interpreted the question at first without paying attention to the title.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sure: just take g(n) = n + halt(n) (where halt(n)=1 if TM number n halts, and 0 ow).

Comment: I think you don't get to choose g.

Comment: I take "can there be" to ask whether for some g there exists an f.
For the interpretation of whether for every g there exists an f, you get a negative answer by taking g=n^{halt(n)}.

Answer (score 9):

It’s not clear to me whether you want a particular pair of functions *f* and *g* with the desired property, or if you’re asking if, for every uncomputable *g*, there exists a computable *f* ∈ Θ(*g*).

In the first case, Noam’s answer applies. Otherwise, the answer is no: just let *g* be growing faster than every computable function (standard example: the [busy beaver function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver)).

Comment: +1 Thanks, for the answer. The interpretation I had intended was the former, whether such a $f$ and $g$ exist